# ¿Como puedo enviar un array para hacer filtros en una tienda online que hago con React y ReactRouter?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Estoy buscando la manera de poder filtrar productos y que estos se filtros se vean reflejados en la URL para que si refresca o comparten el link puedan volver acceder a la vista de los productos con los filtros ya puestos

En el inicio de la Aplicación tengo

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/tienda/:ftipo?/:fcategoria?">
        <Tienda agregarProductoAlCarrito={agregarProductoAlCarrito} />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Y en el componente de Tienda tengo lo siguiente para usar

```
const { ftipo, fcategoria } = useParams();
```

Estoy buscando que se puedan seleccionar más de un fcategoria ya que me quedaría limitado a la primer categoria seleccionada en los filtros

Comment: Considera hacer el [tour] y despues [edit] tu pregunta para incluir un Ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes separar las categorías con `&`, al construir los enlaces deberás gestionarlo para que sean algo así:

```
/tienda/tipo/categoria1&categoria2
```

Y luego cuando recoges los datos, hacer un `split`:

```
const { ftipo, fcategoria } = useParams();

let categories = fcategoria.split("&");
```

Y tendrás las categorías en un array